# Fullscreen option is not available when loading/embedding the video from some other site, other than from youtube.com

Tags: html, angular, video, iframe, fullscreen

I am building an application in Angular, in which I am using Iframe to render the video. The URL, I am passing from the controller to the HTML Iframe source tag as :

this.url2 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://example.com/embed/"+this.video_id_);

(abc.com is a dummy name I am taking here)

here

> video_id_

is what I am getting from the API.

Now the thing is when I am using

```
this.url2 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://youtube.com/embed/"+this.video_id_);
```

then the video is having the Fullscreen button as we can see on every youtube video, but when I am using the other link other than youtube.com, then the controls are missing.

The html code is:

```
<iframe *ngIf="url2" 
     [src]="url2" allowfullscreen="1"
        mozallowfullscreen 
        msallowfullscreen
        oallowfullscreen
        webkitallowfullscreen
     width="100%" height="120%" >
     </iframe>
```

The screenshot for the youtube is:
[image]

In this screenshot, if you will see on the right side of the video, there is the control, when the user will click on that, then the video will play in the fullscreen mode.

The next screenshot is:

[image]

In this screenshot, you will see that the control of getting the video in fullscreen mode is missing.

What can I do to have the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes) of `allowfullscreen`

It says that it only gives the "permission" to the iframe to go in fullscreen mode. The iframe still has to proactively `requestFullscreen()` in order to actually go in fullscreen mode.

Video websites like Youtube, Vimeo etc have all implemented buttons in their interface that implement `requestFullscreen()`. In other words, the Fullscreen button you see in your youtube example is not there because of the `allowfullscreen` attribute. It is there because youtube devs put it there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I implement anything in my HTML code, in order to have that functionality?

Comment: You could add your own button somewhere (maybe position it on top of the iframe with css) that orders the guest iframe to go fullscreen.

https://codepen.io/ssk7833/pen/mVOXXp

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot :)